# Count the number of minutes in shift and distribute them

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time, python-datetime

I have shifts of 10 people, and i want to count the number of minutes by dividing them in early morning shift afternoon shift and night shift, assuming the early morning shift is from 6 am to 12 am afternoon being 12 am to 7 pm and night being 7 pm to 2 am, and people can have shifts overlapping so 1 person can have a shift starting from 10 am to 3 pm which means he will have 2 hrs in morning shift and 3 hrs in afternoon shift.

I have divided the shift in half hrs and distributing them in a for loop but it's complexity is way too high ..any other suggestions to reduce the time complexity would be really appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you add some data sample to question?

Comment: between 2 to 6 are no shifts?

Answer (score 0):

Create helper dictonary by ranges, use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for shifts and aggregate [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) for counts:

```
d = {'early morning':[range(6, 12)], 
     'afternoon':[range(12, 19)], 
     'night':[range(19, 25), range(0, 2)]}

d1 = {y: k for k, v in d.items() for x in v for y in x}
df['shift'] = df['hour'].map(d1)

df1 = df.groupby(['name','shift']).size().reset_index(name='count')
```